# MS SQL Combine 2 tables rows(for each row select all table rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables: 

1 - prices:
PID, Price
2 - prices multipliers:
MID, PriceMultiplier

I need to combine these tables using next approach:
For each multiplier select PID, MID, Price*PriceMultiplier

As I understood using simple query it's not possible, but I can't find way how to do this using stored procedure

Comment: Something's missing - you don't have enough info to solve this, because you did not describe a way to connect the two tables.

Comment: The way is to select each row for each row. For example if we have tables with 10 rows in each then result should be 100 rows set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (from a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815582/ms-sql-combine-2-tables-rows/23815674#comment36637972_23815582)) The way is to select each row for each row

You can use [`CROSS JOIN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for that:

```
SELECT p.PID, m.MID, p.Price * m.PriceMultiplier
FROM Price p
CROSS JOIN Multiplier m
```

This will produce a `{price, multiplier}` pair for each combination of rows from both tables.

Comment: That was thing that I was looking for. Thanks a lot. Can't belive that this was so simple...